# How to minimize queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 tables wthat will need 4 tuples upadated or inserted, for example
Table will have an entry for game and career for each player (2)  SO that is 4 tuples.  Off the top of my head I can only think to do a SELECT  for player1 and game if not exist insert else update,   theh for player1 and a career, .......    This seems like a lot of DB queries is there a better way to handle this?  In PHP PDO MYSQL existing code:

```
CREATE TABLE `standings` (  
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
 `league_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `season_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `statistic_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `wlt` varchar(30) NOT NULL);    


$sth = $dbh->prepare('Select * from standings   
            where league_id=?  and season_id=? and team_id=? and statistic_type_id=$? ');  

$data = $sth->execute(array($l, $s, $t, $st));  

$data = $sth->fetchAll();  

if ($sth->rowCount() == 0) {    
    $wlt = $w . '," . $lo . ',' . $di;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO standings ( id, league_id, season_id,     
                team_id, statistic_type_id, wlt)  
                VALUES( 0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); 

         $data = $sth->execute(array( $l, $s, $t, $st, $wlt)); 

} else {  
    foreach ($data as $row) { 
        $wlt = explode(",", $row['wlt']);   
        $wlt[0] = $wlt[0] + $w;   
        $wlt[1] = $wlt[1] + $lo;    
        $wlt[2] = $wlt[2] + $di;   
        $nwlt = implode(",", $wlt);  

        $sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE standings SET wlt=?   
            where league_id=?  and season_id=? and team_id=? and statistic_type_id=$? ');  

        $data = $sth->execute(array($nwlt, $l, $s, $t, $st)); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace into http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Well not sure how.  So If it does not exits i will insert and replace will work.  but if it does exist then I need to bump  certain fields up.  For example   if the player won the match then I need to bump his win field by 1   and if he threw for 275  then I would need to bump that field by 275.  is there a way to do that with replace?

Comment: yes you can do it REPLACE INTO table set userid=21, field=IF(field AND field = 1, 1, 275).. or something like that as I am not sure about table structure

Comment: CREATE TABLE `standings` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, (primary key) `league_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `season_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `statistic_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `wlt` varchar(30) NOT NULL,      So I do not know the key  I do know league_id, season_id, team_id, and statistic_type_id   the wlt field is a comma seperated strind that I implod/explode to get to teh stats.  ex. 1,0,250    (1 is wins, 0 is losses, 250 is distance)  SO I wnat to end up with 2,0,525 if the tuple exists

Comment: can you share your existing code I mean if check, select query and insert or update query?

Comment: Yes but not sure how to format       $sth = $dbh->prepare('Select * from standings where leaguue_id=$l  and season_id=$s and team_id=$v and stat_type=$st ');     $data = $sth->execute(...)      if ($sth->rowCount() == 0) { insert tuple }     else {   foreach ($data as $row) {  $wlt = explode(",", $row['wlt']);   $wlt[0] = $WLt[0] + $w; $wlt[1] = $wlt[1] + $l; $wlt[2] = $wlt[2] + $d;  $nwlt = implode(",", $wlt);     UPDATE.....same where as above    using the $nwlt